# mousemove parallax only move slightly instead of mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, offset, mousemove

I'm wanting the plane and rocket to only move approx 5% from their original place when the mouse hits the hero-panel area.

this current code makes both images follow and offset where the mouse position is.

Please assist.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hero-panel').mousemove(function (e) {
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('plane'), 1);
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('rocket'), 2);
    });
});

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
    var layer_coeff = 10 / layer;
    var x = ($(window).width() - target.offsetWidth) / 4 - (e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 4)) / layer_coeff;
    var y = ($(window).height() - target.offsetHeight) / 4 - (e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 4)) / layer_coeff;
    $(target).offset({ top: y ,left : x });
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jc0807/c5yke2on/

Thanks

Comment: What plane?  What rocket?  What hero-panel area?  5% of what?  This question is a disaster, please rephrase it.

Comment: @PeteB terribly sorry i provided the wrong fiddle link. Thank you for checking

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense with the new fiddle :)  It's still not clear what the 5% is based on though... the full height of the panel perhaps?

Comment: Are you saying you want them to only move once instead of constantly while the mouse is over the panel?

Comment: @PeteB i basically want them to kind of hover/move slightly from it's starting position when the mouse is in the whole hero-image container. Similar to the parallax mouse follow effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you're looking for:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5yke2on/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var plane = document.getElementById('plane');
    var rocket = document.getElementById('rocket');
    plane.homePos = { x: plane.offsetLeft, y: plane.offsetTop };
    rocket.homePos = { x: rocket.offsetLeft, y: rocket.offsetTop };

    $('#hero-panel').mousemove(function (e) {
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('plane'), 10);
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('rocket'), 20);
    });
});

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
    var x = target.homePos.x - (e.pageX - target.homePos.x) / layer;
    var y = target.homePos.y - (e.pageY - target.homePos.y) / layer;
    $(target).offset({ top: y ,left : x });
};
```

What we're doing here is recording the starting position of the plane and the rocket as a new property 'homePos' on the plane and rocket objects.  This makes it easy to apply the parallax effect as an *offset* from the original positions based on the mouse distance from the object homePos.
If you modify the layer value passed to parallax, the amount of movement will change (we're dividing the mouse offset from the middle of the object's starting position by it, to calculate the new object offset amount).

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question is somehow related to the one above and I didn't want to create a duplicate.

I am using the code bellow to "navigate" into an image on mousemove. The problem is that I cannot manage to make the image fill all the viewable screen area. I've added a red background to the container to show what I mean. The desired result would be to no red background visible.

HTML

```
<div class="m-scene" id="main">
  <div class="scene_element">
    <img class="body" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/nature-background-images2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img.body').mousemove(function(e) {
    parallax(e, this, 1);
  });
});

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
  var layer_coeff = 20 / layer;
  var x = ($(window).width() - target.offsetWidth) / 2 - (e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
  var y = ($(window).height() - target.offsetHeight) / 2 - (e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
  $(target).offset({
    top: y,
    left: x
  });
};
```

CSS

```
.m-scene {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.scene_element {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scene_element img {
   width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

My jsFiddle is: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucian_ilea/sh8sdb0e/2/)

Thank you!